# repeat a list of data in the same file/column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a list of data in a file such as

```
-0.2947990000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.0315420000000000
```

and I would like to repeat this sequence of data 35 times so to have an output file  such as

```
-0.2947990000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.0315420000000000
.
.(x35 times)
.
-0.2947990000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.0315420000000000
```

Comment: Does it have to be awk? with perl, you could do something like `perl -00 -ne 'print $_ x 35' file`

Comment: Is that list the only contents of the original file ? Are the other things in the file that need to be filtered out ? Please clarify

Comment: In a cshell you can do simply: `repeat 35 cat data_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple `for` loop:

```
for i in {1..35}; do cat input_file >> new_file; done
```

Comment: Consider implementing the loop via `while` with counter. The `{1..35}` works in `bash` and `ksh` ( IIRC ) but not in POSIX `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly that input data structure (i.e. no empty lines), and for `awk`s that allow for it (i.e. the last line read is available in the `END` section), try

```
$ awk 'END {for (i=1; i=35; i++) print}' RS= file
-0.2947990000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.0315420000000000
.
.
.
-0.2947990000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.1722064000000000
 0.0315420000000000
```

EDIT: or, even shorter,

```
awk 'END {for (i=35; i--;) print}' RS= file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yes input_file | sed 35q | xargs cat > output_file
```

or with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(ARGC<36)ARGV[ARGC++]=ARGV[1]}1' input_file
awk 'BEGIN{f=ARGV[1]; for(i=35;i--;){while((getline <f) > 0) print; close(f)}}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk this can be done via adding lines of file into array, and iterating through array via nested loop within END statement:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0} END{ for(c=1;c<=35;c++) for(j=0;j<=i;j++) print a[j]}' data.txt
```

Of course, if the number of lines in file is very large it would be more appropriate to `cat` the file multiple times and append as shown in [Roman's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490636/85039)